# How to create a password field that requires at least one alpha character to be entered

Tags: java, blackberry

I work on an application and there is a registration form with password field.

My basic requirement is to make mandatory for a user to insert at least one alpha character to the password field to make password acceptable.

Please, give me a piece of advice, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: EdPassword.getText().toString().

Comment: i have tried to find if there any method

Comment: i have also tried to find that trough matcher is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check is the password String contains atleast a letter Like `1234` is not acceptable but `a123` is acceptable.

You can do this like

```
public boolean containsLetter(String s) {
    if ( s == null)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0;  i < s.length(); i++){
        if(CharacterUtilities.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcibly causing the field to be the focus when it does not contain a character for the password is not a desirable feature.  What if the want to make a correction to the username field, butt cannot switch to it, because the password field is blank.  Instead, disable the submission button until the condition that the password field has at least one character is met.

Using pseudo code:

```
if(field.contents.string.length < 1)
{
confirmButton.enabled = false;
}
else
{
confirmationButton.enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onChange method for password textfield , than in this method check the length of password text field , don't use trim , because user may need spaces .

```
<field object>.getText().lenght != 0 -> Enable submit button.
```

Or at the time of submit check the password field text either it is more than or equal to your  minimum limit.

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
{
    Field f1 = getFieldWithFocus().getLeafFieldWithFocus();
    if(f1 == btn_login)
    {
        if(txtField_userName.getText().trim().equals("") || txtField_password.getText().trim().equals(""))
        {
            String str[] = new String[]{"OK"};
            ButtonPopup.ask("Email or password can not left blank !", str);
        }   
        else
        {
            <Do your work here>

        }
    }
    return super.navigationClick(status, time);
}
```